# Java shows incorrect current year

Tags: java, datetime

I have written code for printing current date.

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMYYYY");
String newdate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

But it gives output as : `29122016`
Actual output should be : `29122015`
The system date is also correct.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Thanks! It worked :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Y` denotes a week year. You should change to:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
```

The [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) has the details:

```
Letter | Date or Time Component | Presentation | Examples
-------+------------------------+--------------+----------
y      | Year                   | Year         | 1996; 96
Y      | Week year              | Year         | 2009; 09
```